# outputting a sentence from shortest word to longest

Tags: java

This is what I currently have been trying to get an output like this:

```
input:  this is a sentence
output: a is this sentence
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a sentance:");
        String text = input.nextLine();
        String[] words = text.split("");
        String temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (words.length - 1); j++) {
                if (words[j].compareTo(words[j + 1]) < 0) {
                    temp = words[j];
                    words[j] = words[j + 1];
                    words[j + 1] = temp;

                }
            }
            System.out.print(words[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: Split the string by " "(space) to separate all words,and sort it using Arrays.sort(words, (a, b)->Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length()));. See this answer for more 
details: !(here)[https ://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866240/how-to-sort-string-array-by-length-using-arrays-sort]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may convert the input to a list and then sort using a lambda:

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a sentence:");
String text = input.nextLine();
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(text.split(" "));
words.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
System.out.println(String.join(" ", words));
```

This prints (for input `this is a sentence`):

```
 a is this sentence
```

Comment: And add a call to `Stream#distinct` to eliminate duplicate words.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test
    public void testSort() {
        Assertions.assertEquals("a is this sentence", sort("this is a sentence"));
    }

    private String sort(String sentence) {
        return Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }
```

// split words by space then sort by length and join words again by space.